# give multiple arguments to subprocess.run input

Tags: python, subprocess

I am new to using subprocess and I would like to know how could we enter multiple inputs.

I have executed the following code to try to do it by myself:

```
process = subprocess.run(['python', '-c', 'print((int(input())+int(input()))*int(input()))'], 
                         input=[7,3,8],text=True, capture_output=True)

print(process.stderr)
```

However, while running the code, I get an error telling me that the input argument must be a string (note that when putting `text=False` I am get the same type of errors saying that the input must be bytes-like).

Then, I would be really gratefull if anyone could help me find how to enter more than one input to a subprocess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take input using the `input` function, you are actually reading a line of binary data from standard input and decoding it into a string. You can pass a bytes object (like `input=b"7\n3\n8"`), or you can have pass a normal string (like `input="7\n3\n8"`) and have it decode it for you by passing `text=True`.

Also, you should check `process.stdout` instead of `process.stderr` for the output. Note that it's a string, so you'll need to wrap `int(...)`.

Comment: Yess thank you, it finally worked for me. Just a little precision if it may help someone else, I used the ```eval()``` function to enter my inputs just like this : ```input=eval("7\n3\n8")```